# Appending tables in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, append

I have 2 large datasets of over 800k rows which I would like to merge into a single table in Access. Thus, I'm using an Append-type of query in Access, but I get an error message saying that it didn't add the rows because of key violations.
The SQL query is the following:

```
INSERT INTO table_name_A
SELECT [table_name_B].*,*
FROM table_name_B
```

Any hint on why I get the error message?

Comment: We need the table definitions so we can see the keys and tell you it's a key problem. Whatever key you have in Table A is being violated when you try to append from Table B.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't understand why you use `[table_name_B].*,*`.  That makes it sound like you're selecting all the columns twice, which is probably not what you had in mind.  Try deleting the ",*" and see how that works.  If you're still getting error messages, post the exact messages as a comment; key violations usually means you're trying to insert a duplicate row or something.  Good luck.